# React Modal how to change Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown menu in my react app just like this:
[image]

and you see there is "Open modal" where I have problem with:
The issue is when I click on it, the modal content shows up inside of the the list which is another component. the code is like:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        
        <CRow>
            
            <CCol xs={12}>
                <CNav>
                    <CNavItem>
                    </CNavItem>
                    <CDropdown variant="nav-item">
                        <CDropdownToggle color="secondary">Dropdown button</CDropdownToggle>
                        <CDropdownMenu>
                            <CDropdownItem><Modal parentSelector={() => document.querySelector('#root')}> </Modal> </CDropdownItem>
                            
                            <CDropdownItem href="#">Another action</CDropdownItem>
                            <CDropdownItem href="#">Something else here</CDropdownItem>
                        </CDropdownMenu>
                    </CDropdown>
                    <CNavItem>
                        <CNavLink href="#">Link</CNavLink>
                    </CNavItem>
                    <CNavItem>
                        <CNavLink href="#" disabled>
                            Disabled
                        </CNavLink>
                    </CNavItem>
                </CNav>
            </CCol>
        </CRow>
    )
}

export default App
```

and here is my modal component:

```
const display = {
    display: 'block'
};
const hide = {
    display: 'none'
};

class Modal extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            toggle: false
        }
    }

    toggle(event) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            toggle: !prevState.toggle
        }));
    }
    render() {
        var modal = [];
        modal.push(
            <div className="modal" style={this.state.toggle ? display : hide}>
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <h4>modal content</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <a className="btn-flat" onClick={this.toggle}>Agree</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <a className="btn" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.state.toggle ? 'Close modal' : 'Open modal'}</a>
                {modal}
            </div>
        );
        
    }
    
}

export default Modal
```

I tried QuerySelector, but didn't work. How can I control which DIV or component, modal can show up?

Comment: You need to extract the state and toggle function out of the modal. Now if you want to create a button to toggle the modal for it. You pass both the function and the state variable based on the click event to toggle the modal to display or not to display